# Adding static data to sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have more than `5 MB` string for my android application. I want to store it in my application and use it. I  have two options:

1. I can use `string-array`.
2. I can use sqlite.

Currently, I am using `string-array`.

Someone suggested that I use sqlite. So, I studied about sqlite. I can now save and fetch data from sqlite. But, I have some issues with it.

Since data is static, I need to put it in the sqlite database. For this, I must have data in both string and when saved, in sqlite form. Using sqlite means my same string data is present at two locations. How can I save from this.

So, to store static data, is it better idea to use sqlite database?

Comment: Do you really need to bloat the memory with ALL the 5 MB of text or you can display the required info from time to time?

Comment: Sorry for being late. This is a book basically. The book is divided chapters and verses. I have changed it in the xml form. So, I need to display all of the files.

Comment: I would rather search for a verse, then find and display the related chapter. This would be more senseful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it makes sense to use sqlite, depends on what you are going to do with the data. If you intend to search it or apply filters to it so you only get certain parts of the data, then using a database makes sense. If it just a bunch of strings, like a story or a documentation it's fine to use a string array or you could also place a simple text file in the assets folder.

If you still want to go for the database, there are ways to put a prefilled database (which in the end is only some file) into your assets folder and move it to dedicated database storage on first start of your app. That way you don't need to have the data two times like you described.

On how to use a prefilled database, see e.g. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper or search stackoverflow; I came across that topic several times already.

Answer (score 0):

Using sqllite shell https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html you can create your database file on your computer and store it in your application under assets folder.

So you should do something like this:

```
sqlite3 assets/databases/mydb.db
sqlite> create table //(here put your creating table script)
and insert string values.
```

After that you can use this library https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper to work with it in your application.

But, I think using string-array or maybe the raw text file in assets is better way, because it allows your to change the content without generation new version of database file file.

Comment: Yes, but searching and filtering takes time in such case.